# Postgres Join that allows for an empty table

Tags: postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following schema, and I'm having a lot of trouble joining these tables properly. I'm trying to get all folders that don't have a file updated in the last 10 mins in them. But I want to include any folders that don't have any files.

```
create table folders (
  id              int,
  table_name      text
);

create table files (
  id              int,
  folder_id       int,
  file_name       text,
  last_updated    timestamp with time zone
);
```

My naive attempt so far is something like the following (this is a re-creation from the CLI):

```
Select t.folder_name from folders t
join files f on (f.folder_id = t.id)
where last_updated < 15m
group by t.id
```

I can get either all folders to show up OR the latest file for each, but not both.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A condition like "a that does not have some b" is usually translated using a `not exists` condition:

```
select fld.*
from folders fld
where not exists (select 1 
                  from files fl
                  where fl.last_updated >= current_timestamp - interval '10' minute
                    and fl.folder_id = fld.id);
```

The subselect will also return "nothing" for folders that don't have any files, thus the `not exists` is true for them as well.

Comment: 6 seconds earlier and almost identical. :)